# Adding dynamic subdomains to my webserver?

Tags: url, .htaccess, domain-name-system, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I'm trying to add a wildcard sub-domain system to my web server, but its still not working,

These are the steps I took:

I made a new file, `vhost.conf`, in the directory
`var/www/vhosts/www.example.com/conf/vhost.conf`.

And I put:

```
ServerAlias *.domain.com
```

Then second of all, I made a new DNS wildcard on Plesk:

```
CNAME *domain.com example.com
```

And then I edited my `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.example.com
RewriteRule (.*)  user.php?user=%1
```

Normally my URL would be:

```
http://www.example.com/user.php?user=solomon
```

But now, I want it like this:

```
http://solomon.example.com
```

But the steps I took still don't work.

:)) What's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper CNAME definition for wildcard domains should be as such:

```
*.example.com CNAME example.com.
```

So in plesk you could try to edit the record and add that dot after the wildcard.

Of course you have to wait a bit for DNS propagation to occur, don't forget that.

Your htaccess also looks a bit wrong, although it should work, referring twice to the beginning of the string is a bit strange, try this instead:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule .*  user.php?user=%1 [L]
```

For more 1and1/Plesk specific info try to read the following tutorial: http://www.1and1faq.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-602.html

Comment: i try to go to solomon.kornar.com, but it shows me the 1and1 page, can you try it please thanks

Comment: It seems that the Apache Vhost is not setup correctly. I'm not sure you can actually do wildcard domains with the hosting you have. I've no experience with 1and1, but it's a possibility that they don't allow it. If you can provide more info feel free.

Comment: i have linux dedicated server, and i also have root access!! so i must be able to do this, i think :)) im so stupid sorry

Comment: Then yeah you should be able to ;) Try to force plesk to reload the stuff using `/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/websrcmng --reconfigure-vhost --vhost-name=example.com` and then `/sbin/service httpd restart`

Comment: can i give you access to my linux server, and see whats wrong, becuase im shit at ssh command!!! please :(

Comment: thats the tutorial i was following, and it was wrong!! lool

Comment: Well I am sorry but I think you should rather ask in the 1and1 forums for specific help, or contact 1and1 support directly. I can not in good conscience let you give me root access to your server.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://solomon.example.com [R=permanent,L]
```

Please refer this link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520140/how-to-redirect-all-urls-to-a-www-subdomain/4520174#4520174

Answer (score 0):

> But the steps I took still don't work

That's not very helpful—**what** didn't work?

Do the names resolve? Does the web server respond to local requests for the domain? (NB the local interface on the server hardware may not be configured to the same address as the public IP&.) You would need to use something like Telnet to connect to the IP before submitting the HTTP request manually from the new host. Is the web server not differentiating between domains as expected? Is the rewrite rule not firing? You mention Plesk—implying that this is a hosted service. Are you sure `mod_rewrite` is available? Have you set up named vhosts on the same server by the same mechanism? How do you know that simply adding a new file in `var/www/vhosts/www.kornar.com/conf/vhost.conf` is all that's required? Usually I'd expect to restart the web server for the changes to be activated.

Comment: thanks for answering, can you try http://solomon.kornar.com this is where my domain  is

Comment: its not redirecting, and i dnt know where that webpage is coming from

Answer (score 0):

Apache already has excellent support for [**mass vhosting**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html); I suggest you take a look at how to set that up.